# How to Resize and reorder bootstrap columns according to screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reorder my bootstrap columns.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row equal">
   <div class="panel  col-lg-7  col-md-7  col-sm-6 col-xs-push-12 "  id="PanelFirst">
     Some content here...
   </div>
   <div class="panel col-lg-5  col-md-5 col-sm-6  col-xs-pull-12 " id="PanelSecond">
     Some Content here....
   </div>
```

I have tried for `col-xs-pull` and `col-xs-push` classes. I have also tried pull-left and `pull-right` class.
I have tried using media query also for smaller screen.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
{
    #PanelFirst {
        float: right;
    }

    #PanelSecond {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

When I am using `col-xs-pull-12` and `col-xs-push-12` classes.. Its is also affecting for larger screens. what I want is- I want to shift entire `PanelSecond` to up and `PanelFirst` to below for `xs` size screen only.

[image: For large screen]
It is fine for large scree but in small screen that login area should be on top. But it is showing like this.

[image: Small Screen]

Comment: Can you please make it a little bit more clear how you want your layout?

Comment: yeah, i am going to add screenshot. hope it will make you more clearer :)

Comment: Use col-md-5 as the class works well for all screens and falls through nicely on all screens

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/4mtMNsjaV2HMTj2vSs6Q?p=preview

Always **think Mobile First** for such cases. It will simplify the answer.

```
<div class="row equal">
     <div class="panel col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-5 col-md-push-7" id="PanelSecond">
       panel second content here....
     </div> 
     <div class="panel  col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-7 col-md-pull-5"  id="PanelFirst">
       panel first content here...
     </div>
   </div>
```

Since you want `PanelSecond` on top, I have changed the html to keep it on top and then `PanelFirst`. (Keeping mobile first css in my mind.)

Then use pull and push to adjust your columns.

**Alignment for lg,md and sm**

[image]

**For xs**

[image]

Comment: I don't want to change for larger screen. If I use this code it will change my panels for medium size screen also..

Comment: You want panelsecond to take 5 cols on right and panelfirst to take 7 cols on left till xs screen size right? And for xs it will take 12 cols. Please correct me if I am wrong. I will also create a demo to share with you.

Comment: 5cols on right and 7 cols on left for md and lg size.. not for 'xs'. for xs i want 12 cols and shift it up for panel second. for sm it will take col6 that is working fine. problem is only to shift up at size xs for col12

Comment: Please check the demo link and the updated answer. I guess that's what you want. The second div will be of 5 cols and will be on right in lg and md. The first div will be of 7 cols and will be on left in lg and md. For sm, the 2nd div will be on right with 6 cols and 1st div will be on left with 6 cols. and in xs the 2nd div will be on top with 12 cols and 1st div will be on bottom with 12 cols

Comment: In you demo you are shifting panels for large screen while for xs size panelfirst is not shifting up.. and that is the only thing that i want,,  :(

Comment: It is working exactly how you want. The form is on top for xs and on right on other screens. Check the demo. I have updated it so that you can understand better.

Comment: thanks for your effort... problem has been solved by reversing the order of panel on code side .. :)

Comment: glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the order and apply push & pull in medium size of columns:

like this:

```
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="panel col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-push-7 col-md-5" id="PanelSecond">
    Some Content here second....
  </div>  
  <div class="panel col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-pull-5 col-md-7"  id="PanelFirst">
    Some content here First...
  </div>  
</div>
```

Reference : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: thanks but Its not working as expected.. It is going out of container class.. and I want to change the order only for smaller screen size

Comment: plz check demo.. it's not going out of container ... https://jsfiddle.net/uozve0me/1/

Comment: PanelFirst is not shifting up for xs size in your demo... you are also shifting at md and lg size :(

Comment: But you want to shift entire PanelSecond to up and PanelFirst to below for xs size screen only.  --and it is work like that:  https://jsfiddle.net/uozve0me/2/

Comment: Thanks... By shifting panels on code made it easy.. :)